# Opportunity without products Validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity-lineitem

How would i create a field (formula?) to check if a opportunity has products that I can use for validation logic:
IF
productscount>0 (or products not null, empty)
AND
Probability>50%
Then - error message " Must add products to the opportunity"

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a built-in field that identifies if an opportunity has a product attached. You can use this in your validation rule like this:

```
AND(NOT(HasOpportunityLineItem), Probability>0.5)
```

Comment: How do you know everything? ))

Comment: awesomeee, din't know there was a flag for this

Comment: @Oleksiy sfdcfox is not a human, sfdcfox is a super computer that salesforce runs on :P May have asked the same question "How do you know everything"

Comment: @Oleksiy I appreciate the flattery, but I definitely don't know everything (not even everything about salesforce.com). I just have the requisite 10,000+ hours of experience needed to be a master.

Comment: @Rao we have to call fim sfdcyoda

Comment: @Oleksiy lol :)

Comment: sfdcfox is Jon skeet of salesforce :)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Create a rollup summary field to show the number of opportunity product

Step 2: AND( rollupsummaryfield >0 , probability > 50%) throw error

Comment: Rollup field isn't necessary, you know.